# Meta Information within Apache config files

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ruby

I have a number of VirtualHosts config files controlling sites served on Ubuntu server using Apache. I'm writing a ruby script to parse these files, and then display information about the site being hosted.

One of the things I'd like to do is display a user friendly name for each site for easier identification, rather than relying on ServerName, or ServerAlias, to determine the site name.  Does anyone know of an Apache configuration directive that exists for this purpose, or for displaying other related meta information about a config file, or will I have to use comments rather than a directive instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're called comments.  You prefix your metadata with a `#`.

Comment: Comments it is then...